# How to split a DataFrame that has a list of dictionaries into individual DataFrame columns?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a json file that I import as a dataframe. One of the columns contains a list of dictionaries. I need to split the dictionaries into individual columns for each row.

```
import urllib
import json
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

f = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(f.text)
docs = json_normalize(data['documents'])
display(docs)    


doc_num      sentence          categories
   1         "I am a dog"      [{"id" : "A"}, {"id" : "B"}, {"id" : "C"}]
   2         "I am a cat"      [{"id" : "C"}, {"id" : "D"}, {"id" : "E"}]
  ...            ...                                ...
```

What I would like my DataFrame to look like is:

```
doc_num      sentence          cat_A    cat_B    cat_C    cat_D   ...
   1         "I am a dog"        1        1        1        0
   2         "I am a cat"        0        0        1        1
  ...            ...            ...      ...      ...      ...
```

I would like my DataFrame to separate the list of dictionaries into individual columns where the column has a "1" for if it belongs in that category, and a "0" if it does not belong to that category.

Comment: `pd.concat([df.drop('categories',1),df.categories.\
          apply(lambda x:pd.Series([i.get('id') for i in x])).\
          pipe(lambda x:x.T.apply(lambda y: pd.np.in1d(pd.np.unique(x.values),y)).\
            T.astype(int).\
            rename(columns = dict(enumerate(pd.np.unique(s.values)))))],1)`

Comment: I tried and this didnt work. Can you elaborate on your answer please?

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: TypeError: ("'<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: what do you get when you run `df.categories.\ apply(lambda x:pd.Series([i.get('id') for i in x]))`?

Comment: I get this: https://imgur.com/a/1bLB5ci

Comment: wait, did the code I provide work in the example you provided?

Comment: The second piece of code did, but the first one did not

Comment: I copied the code and it works with the data you gave. I do not understand why it does not work on your end. I am sorry, I cant be of help

Comment: No worries, I will give it a try on my end again - I think the issue I struggled with the most may have been solved with the code you already provided. Thanks again for your help, I appreciated it! :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help. I think the code is understandable but if you need help let me know. I tested the output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'categories':[[{'id':'A'},{'id':'B'},{'id':'C'}],[{'id':'B'},{'id':'D'}],[{'id':'C',}]]})

all_keys = {}

def get_all_keys(x):

    for d in x:
        if d['id'] not in all_keys:
            all_keys[d['id']] = 1

_,df['categories'].apply(get_all_keys)

for i,key in enumerate(all_keys.keys()):
    all_keys[key] = i
mat = np.zeros((df.shape[0],len(all_keys.keys())),dtype=np.int)
print(mat.shape)
def f(i,x):

    for d in x:

        key = d['id']
        key_index = all_keys[key]
        mat[i][key_index]=1

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    print(i,row)
    f(i,row['categories'])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=mat,columns=all_keys.keys())
df = pd.concat([df,new_df],axis=1)
```